# iOS touch event triggering by movement of other view

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics

Here's the scenario I am trying to implement:

I already have a view that can let user draw doodles by touching inside the view directly (like a doodle canvas). This view implements `touchesBegan`, `touchMoved`, and `touchEnded` handlers to draw lines from touch event parameters.

Now instead of that, I want user to be able to drag and move another UIView on this canvas view and can still draw lines just like they touch directly. For example, user can drag a pen image view on the canvas view to draw pen-style lines.

In this case, how can I transfer the movement of this pen image view to the canvas so it recognize it? One more question: if I want this canvas view to only recognize movements of drag other views rather than touching directly, what I should do?

(Sorry that this question is little too general, just want to get some pointer of it)... Thanks!

Comment: Why drag the image around? Does it help the user over just selecting a style? It certainly won't help performance

Comment: @Wain this is the project requirement... Sorry that I couldn't explain more, but this fits the app's specific scenario.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to look at the problem is

> How can I transfer movement on the canvas into the location of a pen
>   image view?

That's easy. You already have all the code that keeps track of movement in the canvas (touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded), so all you need to do is change to `center` property of the pen view to track the movement in the canvas.  (Obviously, you'll need to apply small X and Y offsets to put the `center` of the pen view at the correct location).

The only non-obvious detail that you need to be aware of is that the pen view must have `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`.  That way, the pen view won't interfere with touches reaching the canvas view.

Note that `UIImageView` has user interaction disabled by default, so you don't need to do anything if the pen view is a `UIImageView`. However, if you're using a generic `UIView` to display the pen, then you need to disable user interaction in storyboard under the *Attributes inspector* or disable it in code, e.g. in `viewDidLoad`.